# How can I get integer and char separately in such a simple string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, parsing

I have strings like: "7d" , "5m" , "95d" etc.

I need to find simple way to be able to get integer and char in the end separately.

How can I achieve this:

```
int number = GetNumber("95d"); //should return 95
char code = GetCode("95d"); // should return d
```

Comment: What about incorrect string values? Do you want to handle it in some way?

Comment: This looks to me almost like 7d, as in a double value of 7, and 5m, like 5 in decimal. If this is in the right neighborhood, would you potentially have "5.0m"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple alternative to the RegEx solutions.

```
string letters = Seperate( "95d",  c => Char.IsLetter( c ) );
string numbers = Seperate( "95d", c => Char.IsNumber( c ) );

static string Seperate( string input, Func<char,bool> p )
{
    return new String( input.ToCharArray().Where( p ).ToArray() );
}
```

You could make 'Seperate' an extension method on string to make things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

These are the expressions:

```
[^\d]+ <- not digit
\d+ <- digits
```

---

EDIT

```
    static int GetNumber(string text)
    {
        string pat = @"\d+";
        int output;
        // Instantiate the regular expression object.
        Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match m = r.Match(text);
        if (int.TryParse(m.Value, out output))
            return output;
        else
            return int.MinValue; // something unlikely
    }

    static char GetChar(string text)
    {
        string pat = @"[^\d]";
        int output;
        // Instantiate the regular expression object.
        Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match m = r.Match(text);
        return m.Value.Length == 1 ? m.Value[0] : '\0';
    }
```

You really only need to create that `RegExp` object once, not on each method call.

Comment: How could the user capture the values that those expressions would match?

Comment: @Anthony Pegram :  Both functions return the captured value.  Or do you mean in the case of multiple return values?

Comment: @Eric, my comment is older than his revision. ;) Check the history for proper context.

Comment: Second function is named GetChar and returns string. It's confusing a little.

Comment: @pencilCake, was this helpful?

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "95d";
int number = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1));
char code = Char.Parse(s.Substring(s.Length - 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

A regex is probably overkill -- the examples you've proved have a very simple, consistent format. Try the following functions as a starting point:

```
public int GetNumber(string input)
{
   return int.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1));
}


public char GetCode(string input)
{
   return input.Last();
}
```

I say "as a starting point" because you'll need to consider edge cases -- how will you handle empty strings? Can a string end with more than one letter character, and if so, how will you handle this? Hopefully these examples get the wheels turning.

Comment: If I pass you "5m", your GetNumber function will throw. If I pass you "95d", your function will return 9. Are you sure this is a good starting point?

Answer (score 2):

```
    private char GetChar(string t)
    {
        return t.Substring(t.Length - 1, 1)[0];
    }

    private int GetNumber(string t)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(t.Substring(0, t.Length - 1));
    }
```

Edit: second version of GetNumber function with 'TryParse' instead of 'Parse':

```
    private int GetNumber(string t)
    {
        int result;
        if(Int32.TryParse(t.Substring(0, t.Length - 1), out result) == false)
        {
             // you can handle here incorrect 't' value if you want
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Always Int32.TryParse is the best way 2 go.

Comment: @zenwalker. I've added alternative function version using TryParse instead of Parse

Answer (score 2):

```
public int GetNumber(string input)
{
    string result = "";

    foreach (Char c in input)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c))
            result += c;
    }

    return Convert.ToInt32(result);
}

public string GetCode(string input)
{
    string result = "";

    foreach (Char c in input)
    {
        if (!Char.IsDigit(c))
            result += c;     // or return the char if you want only the first one.
    }

    return result;
}
```

Did not test but to me it looks like the best way to achieve this. It also is the method that provides the most flexibility compared to other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
public class NumberSuffixParser
{
    private static readonly Regex rxPattern = new Regex( @"^(?<number>\d+(\.\d+)?)(?<suffix>\p{L}+)$" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture ) ;

    public void Parse( string value , out decimal number , out string suffix )
    {
        if ( value == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("value") ;
        Match match = rxPattern.Match( value ) ;
        if ( ! match.Success ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value") ;
        number = decimal.Parse( match.Groups["number"].Value ) ;
        suffix =                match.Groups["suffix"].Value   ;
        return ;
    }

    public decimal ParseNumber( string value )
    {
        decimal number ;
        string  suffix ;
        Parse( value , out number , out suffix ) ;
        return number ;
    }

    public string ParseSuffix( string value )
    {
        decimal number ;
        string  suffix ;
        Parse( value , out number , out suffix ) ;
        return suffix ;
    }

}
```

Another, slightly more simplistic, but quite flexible approach follows. It will happily parse stuff like '789xyz', '1234' or 'abcde'. If it doesn't find a integer prefix, it returns 0. The suffix is whatever follows the integer prefix: if it doesn't find a suffix, it returns nil ('').

```
public static void Parse( string value , out int number , out string suffix )
{
  number = 0 ;
  int i = 0 ;
  for ( i = 0 ; i < value.Length && char.IsDigit( value[i] ) ; ++i )
  {
     number *= 10 ;
     number += ( value[i] - '0' ) ;
  }
  suffix = value.Substring(i) ;
  return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
static string getNumber(String str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char chr in str)
    {
        try
        {
            int x = int.Parse(chr.ToString());
            sb.Append(chr);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

static string getCode(String str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char chr in str)
    {
        try
        {
            int x = int.Parse(chr.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.Append(chr);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}



// 95
Console.WriteLine(getNumber("95d"));
// a
Console.WriteLine(getCode("95d"));
```

Comment: This is not something you should be doing. For one, exceptions should not be used for control flow.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, yes and thanks for pointing this out but I was just trying to show a diferent way of doing it.

Comment: that's fine, but do you see why this is not a good approach? There are better ways to test if you are dealing with a number than trying to convert it and catching the exception when it fails. Particularly egregious is when you are trying to get the character code, the `catch` block is desired path. Look into better methods of parsing or validating inputs.

Comment: When you got TryParse, why go for exception handling. not good my friend.

Comment: @zenwalker, as I said before it is another way of doing it, Of course you're free to point whatever you want even if it is not a constructive comment. But what would it be of "stackoverflow" only by accepting "ruled" answers? This community is great because of people and the liberty to help.